# Android Firebase Notification with Wifi and Mobile Data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my Android app, I open 2 Network Wifi and Mobile Data at same time.
Wifi connect to Hotspot but without internet connection and I force App using Mobile Data network as Default.

I send a message from Firebase console, but my app won't receive the message until I turn off wifi.

Please help me with this case!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that the Notifications works on Mobile Data only and not on Wifi ?
It could be that your local network has a firewall and some ports are blocked. Here is what google say about FCM

> If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with GCM in order for your GCM client apps to receive messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169.